# Efeito surgir sem criar barra de rolagem

Tags: css3

É possível criar o efeito abaixo sem que o browser crie barras de rolagem? (IE10 +)

```js
function trocaEfeito(){
  document.querySelector('.efeito').classList.toggle('ativo')
}
```

```css
*{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.conteudo{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000140, #0072BD);
}

.efeito{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform .6s ease;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000, #000140);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.efeito.ativo{
  transform: translateY(0);
}

button{
  height: 2rem;
  width: 4rem;
  margin: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='conteudo'>
      <button onclick='trocaEfeito()'>clique</button>
    </div>
    <div class='efeito'>
      <button onclick='trocaEfeito()'>fechar</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Então, você pode usar a propriedade `overflow` no `body` do seu código CSS.

A propriedade `overflow` especifica quando o conteúdo de um elemento de nível de bloco deve ser cortado, exibido com barras de rolagem ou se transborda do elemento.

```js
function trocaEfeito(){
  document.querySelector('.efeito').classList.toggle('ativo')
}
```

```css
*{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.conteudo{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000140, #0072BD);
}

.efeito{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform .6s ease;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000, #000140);
}

.efeito.ativo{
  transform: translateY(0);
}

button{
  height: 2rem;
  width: 4rem;
  margin: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='conteudo'>
      <button onclick='trocaEfeito()'>clique</button>
    </div>
    <div class='efeito'>
      <button onclick='trocaEfeito()'>fechar</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Guias:

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

[MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)