# jquery - Animar elemento na entrada e na saída com meu código atual

Tags: jquery

OBS: O site onde preciso usar esse efeito tem um scroll horizontal. Eu preciso com o código atual, com o código dessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/325758/efeito-surgir-sem-criar-barra-de-rolagem) não funcionou pois o plugin que estou usando para fazer a rolagem horizontal trava.

Estou querendo que quando o usuário clique no botão a div apareça vindo do bottom. E quando clique no botão esconder que vai estar na outra div que ele desapareça saindo para o bottom novamente.

Outra questão também é que quando o usuário já executou uma vez a ação volte ao normal. Que se ele tentar executar novamente ela funcione, não é o caso ali pois depois de executada ele vem por cima.

Código no [codepen](https://codepen.io/lucas-granvilla-da-silva/pen/wEzXpr) também.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#mostrar', function(){
      $('.secundaria').css('display','block');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#esconder', function(){
      $('.secundaria').css('display','none');
      $('.secundaria').removeClass('slideInUp');
      $('.secundaria').addClass('slideInDown');
    });
```

```css
* {margin:0;}
.principal {background: #6EC24E;height: 100vh;z-index:1;}
.secundaria {background: #538193;height: 100vh;z-index:2;position:absolute;top: 0;width: 100%;display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css">
<div class="principal">
  <h1>Div Principal</h1>
  <button id='mostrar'>mostrar</button>
</div>
<div class="secundaria animated slideInUp">
  <h2>Div Secundária</h2>
  <button id='esconder'>esconder</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, vc quer que na primeira vez ela aparece entrando por cima e saindo por baixo, e se o cara clicar novamente ela aparece vindo por baixo e depois saindo por baixo também é isso?

Comment: Não, eu quero que ela apareça por baixo e sai por baixo. Mas se ele executou uma vez se tu testar o código ela funciona só na primeira vez, depois ela vem sempre por cima. Quero que ela venha sempre por baixo. E quando ele esconder ela tem que sumir com animação também.

Comment: Muito simples é só retirar a linha `$('.secundaria').removeClass('slideInUp');`

Comment: não é a mesma coisa dessa pergunta ? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/325761/21112

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Efeito surgir sem criar barra de rolagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/325758/efeito-surgir-sem-criar-barra-de-rolagem)

Comment: LeAndrade: Sim, isso resolve a segunda situação, mas na saída está sem animação.

Comment: Pedro: Não é a mesma coisa que o rapaz pediu nessa da barra de rolagem, mas acredito que posso usar o código dele pra fazer esse efeito que eu quero.

Comment: Não funcionou. Mais detalhes no início da minha pergunta.